# how to get a list of the last ten years in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get a list of the last 10 years in oracle ?

This is my attempt

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT to_char(add_months(sysdate,-24),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-36),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-48),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-60),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-72),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-84),'yyyy') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Make an effort. Try something.

Comment: list as all 365*10 dates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort was shown by OP.

Comment: Gonna need more info than that.  You mean the last 10 year values?  What date format?  Last 10 years of table names?  Backups?  Versions?

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Answer (score 21):

Let me start with a simple trick

```
SELECT LEVEL FROM
DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

This would generate rows from 1,2....10.

It works because, `CONNECT BY` will try to chain rows. Each would have a LEVEL. Now we mention `LEVEL <= 10` and hence, 10 rows are generated.!!!

Your question now is, subtract 12 months from `SYSDATE` 10 times..

So, the answer would be

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-LEVEL+1 FROM
DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Now, you could kick start your creativity to customize this sql as you wanted.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Maheswaran !!!! this was quite insightful for me thank you Sir !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the connect by level "trick" to generate rows:

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), -12*(level -1)), 'yyyy') yr
from   dual
connect by level <= 10; -- possibly 11 if you want this year along with the previous 10 years

YR  
----
2015
2014
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007
2006
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive query and some basic math will accomplish this:

```
SELECT     CAST (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'yyyy') AS NUMBER) - LEVEL + 1 AS year
FROM       DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```